# Remotely bring a computer out of screen saver

Tags: windows

Is there any way to remotely send a command to bring a Windows 8 machine out of screen saver (blank screen)?  Maybe sending a down arrow command.  We are putting together a demo for a trade show and one of the request was to be able to turn on several displays at once that will be showing the customer’s software.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, and I couldn't just disable the screensaver, I'd install some remote control software (like a flavor of VNC) and shoot an innocuous keypress or mouse movement to them. There are a variety of tools out there that can do that, including command-line tools that could be scripted.

Comment: I have looked into VNC and that may be what I have to use.  Was hoping for a script that could send a "down arrow" command or something similar.  Need to do this for 6 machines at the same time.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of command-line VNC clients out there. Here's a Python-based one, just based on a 30 second search: https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool